# <asp:LinkButton> make partial text italics

Tags: asp.net

I have the following control:

```
       <asp:LinkButton ID="vid3" runat="server" CssClass="Hyptext" TextDecorations="None" Text ="Part 1 - Sample " OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"/>
```

For the text, where it says Part 1, I need to make that be italics. Sample one can be what styling Hyptext has it as

I tried putting  but was not successful. Any idea.

Comment: try this: <i>Part1</i> - Sample

Comment: This is a nice example why people should start learning html+css first, before they dive into asp.net...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a pseudo-class:

```
.Hyptext:first-letter { }
```

That will style the first letter in your link, but that is the extent of that.